# Using virtual IP with stunnel and haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, stunnel

We have a load-balancer setup, in which an HTTPS Request flows through the following steps:-

```
Client -> DNS -> stunnel on Load-Balancer -> HAProxy on LB -> Web-Server
```

This setup works perfectly when stunnel is listening to the local IP of the Load-Balancer.

However in our setup we have 2 load-balancers and we want to be able to listen to a virtual IP, which only ever exists on one LB at a time (keepalived flips the IP to the second LB if the first one falls over).

HAProxy has no problem in doing this (and I can ping the assigned virtual IP on the load-balancer I'm testing), but it seems stunnel hates the concept.

Has anyone achieved this before (below is my stunnel config - as you can see I'm actually listening for ALL traffic on 443):-

```
cert= /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt
key = /etc/ssl/certs/mykey.key
;setuid = nobody
;setgid = nogroup

pid = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pid
debug = 3
output = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.log

socket=l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket=r:TCP_NODELAY=1

[https]
accept=443
connect=127.0.0.1:8443
TIMEOUTclose=0
xforwardedfor=yes
```

Sorry for the long-winded question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to allow non-existent interfaces to be bound to by programs (like stunnel, HA-proxy). So that when keepalived flips the virtual IP onto that box, the programs are already listening and waiting for traffic on that interface.

This can be done by modifying your `/etc/sysctl.conf` by including the key/value pair of:

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

More here: http://nbevans.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/safely-pairing-haproxy-with-virtual-network-interface-providers-like-keepalived-or-heartbeat/

You'd then do best modifying your stunnel and HA-proxy configs to hard-code the bind to the specific virtual interface IP. Rather than leaving it "open".

Comment: We had already done this, as its a required step I'll mark is as the answer as its likely to help others in a similar situation.

In our case it was actually simply a misconfiguration of keepalived!